# How to parse/get variables from scss/sass via dart-sass/node-sass

Tags: node.js, sass, node-sass, dart-sass

Have a question. Maybe you can help me.

Is it possible to get a variables info from rendering the `scss` file via `dart-sass`.

For example, I have a `style.scss`:

```
$md: 768px;

.class {
  min-height: 0;
}
```

And running this script:

```
const path = require('path')
const sass = require('sass')

const res = sass.renderSync({file: path.join(__dirname, 'style.scss')})

console.log(res.css.toString())
```

I've got the result: `.class { min-height: 0; }`. I've checked the documentation and didn't find anything related to the render process and ger the `scss` file content rather than `css` file content as a string.

Thanks a lot. Have a nice day.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use 'fs' module and regexp or postcsc-scss to deal with the variables.

Link: https://github.com/sass/dart-sass/issues/1231